# Where does Microsoft Word store user-defined keyboard accelerators?

Tags: microsoft-word

I like using EMACS, so in Microsoft Word I set up keyboard accelerators for the EMACS control keys. At my new organization they refresh the Microsoft Word every few months and wipe out all of my customizations. I'd like to know where these accelerators are stored so I can save them and then restore them.

For example, I go to options and make ^a map to `Start of Line` by going to Word Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Keyboard shortcuts Customize, like this:

[image]

I'm also looking for the best way that I could create them. Doing each one manually in the Word user interface is time consuming. Is this something that I should do with a toolbar or a Visual Basic add-in?

Once I have them created, it would great to have a way to export and import them, rather than just saving `Normal.dot` into another directory.

Comment: It might be worth telling us what "accelerators" you are talking about and briefly describe how to set one up just so we are clear what you are talking about. Word has a lot of hotkeys and methods of customisation.

Comment: For example hotkeys set up via File -> Options -> Customise Ribbon apparently end up in the "normal.dotm" file https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea

Answer (score 0):

### Keyboard shortcuts are stored in documents or templates, in the Normal.dotm template by default.

See [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts in Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330), my article on the Microsoft site. Most effective is probably to store them in a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) other than the Normal.dotm file, preferably the same template holding the macro or AutoText entry being referenced.

In vba, they are called [keybindings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.keybindings.add). I don't know that it is any more efficient to assign them using vba than manually through the dialog.

Chris Woodman created an [Organizer for Keyboard shortcuts](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ChrisWoodman) to allow them to be moved from one document/template to another a long time ago, but it still works in modern versions of Word. I do not know if it works on the Mac.

Here is my article on [Creating a List of Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=1589698042191).